# Como fazer uma validação pela URL com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

estou trabalhando em um projeto.. porem preciso fazer uma validação pegando a url atual.. Ex:

```
If(url('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')){
    // Aqui vem minha lógica
}
```

Como faço isso com AngularJS('sou novato em angular..') ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual validação?

Comment: da url brother..

Comment: Que tipo de validação Brother?

Comment: Você quer checar a URL da barra de endereço ou validar uma URL que veio de um INPUT? Explica isso direito por favor.

Comment: pegando a url atual... fui bem explicito na pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode e deve fazer isso utilizando o JavaScript.

Basta usar o `window.location.href`.

Ele vai ter retornar a URL que você está no momento.

Dessa forma você pode fazer:

```
if(window.location.href == 'www.google.com'){
    //Sua lógica aqui
}
```

Para mais informações sobre o window.location, [veja aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).